# Apache SetEnv boolean value

Tags: apache

Is it not possible to pass a boolean value to $_SERVER with apache?

I tried `SetEnv TEST true` but it parses `true` as a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you put `false`, yes this parses to a string. You will have to put `0`, this equals false or `1` if equals true.

Example:

`SetEnv TEST 0` parses to `false`

`SetEnv TEST 1` parses to `true`